# rails routing: combine index and show actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have an existing search-based app that's being ported to Rails. Due to the legacy nature, I need to preserve existing URLs of the form:

```
/books          # search all books
/books/fiction  # search books with :category => fiction
```

I have these mapped to the `index` & `show` actions of my controller, and it works fine, but the code and markup for showing all books vs a particular category of books is virtually identical.

What's the best way to combine the `show` and `index` actions? For this app `index` is really a degenerate case of `show` with `:category => nil`.

I can do:

```
def index
   show
   render "show"
end
```

but that seems kind of ugly. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Rails?

Comment: Doesn't show already render show?

Comment: Perhaps, but afterwards it complains that it cannot find index.html.erb.

Comment: IIRC you'd need to "return show", but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply use one route with an optional category:

```
get '/books(/:category)' => 'books#search'
```

and then in `BooksController`:

```
def search
    # Look at params[:category], if it is there then use it
    # to search, if it isn't there then list 'em all.
    @results = ...
end
```

Then you have just one route, one controller, one view (to rule them all and in the darkness bind them) and no duplication or chicanery.

Comment: @Dave: That's one of my favorite words.

Comment: Ah that works great. I wasn't aware of the (/:optional) syntax, which maps nicely to my existing Wicket URLs. I was tripped up by initially mounting it as a resource, but explicitly listing the GET routes works nicely. Thanks.

Comment: @CaffeineComa: You don't need the whole CRUD set up so there's no need for `resource` here. The [Rails Routing from the Outside In Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is worth reading.